# Bluemix MongoDB create service error

Tags: mongodb, ibm-cloud

When I try to create a MongoDB experimental service I get this error:

> cf create-service MongoDB 100 mongodb01
>   FAILED
>   Server error, status code: 500, error code: 10001, message: An unknown error occurred.

Answer (score 0):

The experimental *mongodb* service is experiencing some issues during the provisioning of new instances. You can monitor the status of each service on the [Bluemix Status Page](https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/support/#status).
Please note that the [Bluemix Labs Catalog](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/labs/) contains experimental runtimes and services that might be unstable or change frequently, and might be discontinued at short notice.
Alternatively you could use [MongoDB by Compose](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/mongodb-by-compose/) from the [Bluemix Catalog](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/). In this way when you experience similar problems you can get technical support. You can open a support request directly from your Bluemix console using the support/help widget: doing this you'll involve IBM support team in checking and fix the issue. They will be able to perform in-depth investigation of your error.